# Unable to POST data from mobile App to Laravel 4 Application

Tags: php, android, laravel, laravel-4, http-post

I have an android application which sends some data in a POST request to my web application built with Laravel 4. I tried testing the web application by sending a crafted POST request from the REST Console chrome extension. I have used Resource routing in my application, and so in the "store" method of the controller, I tried to get the POST data using `Input::get("key")`.  This however gives me "null" . Even `Input::all()` returns null.

Can someone help me figure out how I can achieve this. I cannot use Model binding directly, as I need to perform some validation on the data before storing it.

```
 $request = Request::instance();
 $content = $request->getContent();
 dd($content);
```

This snippet printed out the data that has been passed out via POST viz. `string(25) "test=12121&variable=12123"`.
Weirdly enuff `dd($_POST)` gave `array(0) {}`

Comment: Do you have `csrf` filter enabled for that route ?